# Analysis of changing correlation

Tags: correlation

Given a correlation matrix M and after an event, M changes.

What is the best way to analyse the change? Verify significance (presumably T-test, ANOVA..)

Currently looking at the %, count & average of strong + & - correlation coefficients. Running T-tests and ANOVA.

Thanks!